# Am I correct in assuming voltage is used to describe two different concepts?

Tags: voltage

I am hobbyist trying to gain a strong understanding of the basics of electronics.

So far I have been confused in trying to understand voltage and its relationship with current by its use to describe what seems to me to be two different concepts.

One concept is the force a voltage source applies to a conductor to get current flowing.  The other concept is the amount of energy required to get a charge from one point to another.

For example, the energy required to move an electron through a resistor. Is my understanding here correct?

Comment: Volts are not units of energy. Electron-volts (eV) are.

Comment: I think spending some time understanding Ohm's law would answer his question and increase his understanding of electronics.

Answer (score 2):

Both your concepts seem to be somewhat poorly worded

> ... being the force a voltage source applies to a conductor to get current flowing

Let's not deal with 'to get current flowing', dynamics is yet another problem, let's just handle the steady state. If you've set up a situation where current flows through a conductor, then there is a voltage across that conductor. Neither 'causes' the other, they both happen at the same time. Their ratio is referred to as the resistance of the conductor. Some materials will have a reasonably constant and linear resistance, metals for instance, and these get used for 'resistors'.

> ... and the other being the amount of energy required to get a charge from one point to another. for example, the energy required to move an electron through a resistor.

Voltage has the units of energy/charge. If one unit of charge, one Coulomb or one ampere.second, takes 1 Joule of energy to move it from one place to another, then there's one Volt potential difference between those places. For instance if a resistor dissipates 1 J of heat when 1 C flows through it, then there's 1 V across it.

The first definition is talking about moving charge through a resistor. It's expressed in hand-wavy terms, but it can be made exact with the concept of resistance. It's unfortunate that it seems to express a causative direction 'the voltage causing the current'. Either can appear to cause the other, depending on how you set the situation up.

The second definition is talking about moving charge from anywhere to anywhere, including through a resistor, and the energy required to do that, as a basis for defining the volt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using two different analogies to explain voltage.
Voltage is really one concept.

Another term for voltage is potential difference.
This is similar to the concept of water in a pipe.
When the pipe is level there is no potential difference between the two ends of the pipe and the water in the pipe does not move (it has no current).
However, when you raise one end of the pipe there is now a difference between the two ends of the pipe and the water moves (has current).

This is similar to way voltage works.  If both "ends" of a circuit are at the same potential (voltage) then there is no current in the wire.

This is why we think of the ground side as being at 0 potential (or voltage) and the battery source to be at some voltage like 3V.  When there is a difference between the two parts of the circuit you will have current.

This is of course an incomplete example, but hopefully will get you to a better understanding.

Voltage can also be thought of as the "pressure" just as in the pipe there is water pressure.  In a pipe that is laying on flat ground there is no pressure.
The same thing with a wire.  If there is no battery source creating pressure in the wire, there is no movement of electrons.
These are just concepts to get an idea of what is happening with voltage and current and how they are related but different.
Here's a article I wrote up to explain [how resistors work using the pipe and valve analogy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1244410/Practical-Electronics-For-Makers-Part-of-N-4). It may help a bit since it has diagrams.

It's a part of a series of articles that [may help you learn early electronics concepts](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1223855/Practical-Electronics-For-Makers-Part-of-N).  They are all free and you may find them useful.

Here's a nice set of definitions of potential difference from wordnik:

[image: wornik potential difference]

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and understand Ohms law.

There are two equations:

1. U = I * R
2. P = U * I

Where:
U = Voltage
I = Amperage
R = Resistance
P = Power in watts

Or in water terminology:
U = Water pressure
I = Water flow
R = tube/orifice resistance
P = Power

Given the first equation you can see that if you raise U(voltage), I(Amperage) rises acordingly assuming the resistanse is kept the same. (Which it often is)

Given the second equation we need to understand the curcuit a bit to understand what is happening. In a normal circuit it is not possible raising the Voltage without affecting the Current, As we described in the first equation.
But lets assume: If we raise the voltage on a circuit, but also regulate the current to be the same(by increasing the resistance). Then the power would increase acordingly.